# php public static $var = $var2

Tags: php, variables

I have a php-newsletter script which stores emails in the "data.txt"

The file is defined this way:

```
class Newsletter {

    public static $ListFile = 'data.txt';

    ..
}
```

Is it possible to replace the `data.txt` by a variable when working with
public static expressions?

i.e.:

```
public static $ListFile = $datafile
```

Comment: Not it the definition, but you can change it in a method

Comment: It's fine but you have to load it in constructor or method, not passing it as a definition. Instead it works with defined superglobals (define()). Also because at class load $datafile is empty.

Comment: `Class::var = $newVar;` should work.

Comment: I would suggest not making it static but an actual property of an object or use getters and setters and declare it private or protected...

Comment: If it is static, can't be equal to variable, because variables aren't static, its kinda self-explanatory?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable in the declaration, because at that point that variable would be empty. You can either set it to a value that has been set with `define()` or you can set it in a function, for example the constructor:

```
class Newsletter {

    public static $ListFile;

    function __construct($datafile) {
        $self->$ListFile = $datafile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a variable be static if you appoint it in your constructor?

Comment: $this->$ListFile or self::$ListFile

Comment: @Peter It's static because it is declared that way, it doesn't matter if it is modified in the constructor or someplace else. The constructor is just a sample in this case, it is convenient because it is the first function called upon instantiation and no further calls are required.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Isn't the whole idea of static methods and variables that you don't construct the class before calling a method or variable?

Comment: No, the point of static variables is that you can share the same value over multiple instances or access them without instantiating them at all. There are use cases where you can set them in a constructor

Comment: `$this->$ListFile` would have to mean that `$ListFile` is actually a variable in the method scope. It isn't, so all this example does is raise a big fat notice/warning... It should have been `self::$ListFile` or `static::$ListFile` ... But it is totally bonkers if you would choose to change a static var when instantiating a class, other than if the class would have its own registry...